# RSA Encryption Encode using Android Decrypt using apache codec Issue

Tags: java, android, encryption, base64, rsa

1) I have a private key in a txt file

2) I have written a decrypt method

while running the decrypt method I am getting the below mentioned exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import android.util.Base64;
public static String decrypt(String inputString, byte[] keyBytes) {
    String resultStr = null;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Random generator = new Random(mDay);
    int num = (generator.nextInt()) % 100;
    String salt = "XXwerr" + num;
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception privateKey:::::::::::::::::  "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
         //Also tried 
        // Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(inputString, Base64.NO_CLOSE));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception privateKey1:::::::::::::::::  "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (decodedBytes != null) {
        resultStr = new String(decodedBytes);
        System.out.println("resultStr:::" + resultStr + ":::::");
        resultStr = resultStr.replace(salt, "");
    }
    return resultStr;

}
```

Following is the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    File file = new File("/Users/buta1/Downloads/private.txt");

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try {
        // convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

        // for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
        // System.out.println((char)bFile[i]);
        // }
        decrypt("08F8CFE58F2E707C314F4D7894E0F1", bFile);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**THE ENCRYPTION METHOD USED IS AS follows USING ANDROID Base64 class**

```
 public static String encrypt(String inputString, byte [] keyBytes)
     {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     int mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     //System.out.println("Day of month :::" + mDay);
     String encryptedString = "";
     Key publicKey = null;
     try {
     Random generator = new Random(mDay);
     int num = (generator.nextInt() ) % 100;
     String salt = "xx"+num;
     inputString += salt;
     X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
     KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
     publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception rsaEncrypt:::::::::::::::::  "+
     e.getMessage());
     }
     // Encode the original data with RSA public key
     byte[] encodedBytes = null;
     try {
     Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
     c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
     encodedBytes = c.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
     encryptedString =
     Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.NO_CLOSE);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception rsaEncrypt:::::::::::::::::  "+
     e.getMessage());
     }

     return encryptedString;
     }
```

After using commons codec Base 64

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding ");
```

getting  following error

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:365)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at RSAEncryption.decrypt(RSAEncryption.java:41)
    at RSAEncryption.main(RSAEncryption.java:108)
```

Comment: The stack trace is telling you where the exception is being thrown. Try cutting this down to a smaller piece of code that isolates the error.

Comment: Base64 decoding is falling

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to run Android code from inside your IDE with the `android.jar` on your classpath (e.g. by using the ADT Plugin in eclipse). Then this looks like "working as intended" (cf. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33188).

The `android.jar` only contains stub implementations for all classes, because the intended way would be to run that code inside an emulator.

If you are trying to write code for Android and you find running the code inside an emulator to be too cumbersome, you could try [Roboelectric](http://robolectric.org/), which basically replaces all those stubs with real implementations and allows you to run the code from inside your IDE.

On the other hand, if you are *not* trying to write code for Android you can simply replace `android.util.Base64` with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` or `java.util.Base64.Decoder` (since Java 8).

Comment: Thanks Marvin... Which package should I use to decrypt the encrypted string? The encryption is done using Base 64 from android.jar. Coz the decryption part has to be done outside any device, for analytic purpose after collecting the data.

Comment: @Dutta: If the decryption is not running on a device, you should be fine with one of the replacements mentioned.

Comment: I used commons codec but                            `Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");`  getting following exception    'javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:365)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
 at RSAEncryption.decrypt(RSAEncryption.java:41)
 at RSAEncryption.main(RSAEncryption.java:108)'